# Access Form live display

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to make a live display in a form. There are 3 sub form to display: `Display 1`, `Display 2` and `Display 3`. From `7:30:00 AM` to `4:30:00 PM`, every `30 Seconds` it will change display. I have tried stacking the 3 display together and making 1 of the `visible = yes` while the other 2 `visible = no`. But i do not know how to make a continuous loop where `every 30 Seconds`, it changes the display's visible.
For the `7:30:00 AM` to `4:30:00 PM`, i'm using the `TimeSerial Function`.

Comment: Use the Form_Timer event to change the Subform control source object every 30s

Answer (score 0):

Set the visibility of Display1 to True and of the others to False. Put this code in form after you double click form event "On Timer":

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private DisplayNo As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.TimerInterval = 1000 * 30 ' 30 seconds
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Display1.Visible = False
    Display2.Visible = False
    Display3.Visible = False

    If DisplayNo = 0 Or DisplayNo = 3 Then
        DisplayNo = 1
    Else
        DisplayNo = DisplayNo + 1
    End If

    Select Case DisplayNo
        Case 1
            Display1.Visible = True
        Case 2
            Display2.Visible = True
        Case 3
            Display3.Visible = True
        Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```